# Use of a Vue.Mixin within a Vue.Filter not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

[I'm using the latest vue 2.x, vuex, & vue-cli 3]

I'm trying to use a Mixin within a Vue filter as follows in order to transform this string

> /Date(1546329600000)/

that I get from a server into a java-script date (the following code is in my main.js file, right before I create the Vue instance):

```
// Mixins:
Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        parseDateTicks: str => str.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "")
    }
});


// Filters:
Vue.filter('dateTime', (date) => {
  if(date){
    //date = date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
    date = this.parseDateTicks(date);
    return new Date(+date).toLocaleString();
  }
  else{
    return '';
  }
});
```

The part that doesn't work is

```
date = this.parseDateTicks(date);
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Unable to get property 'parseDateTicks' of undefined or null reference"
```

Is this not possible in Vue.js ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant access this in filter. Filters supposed to be pure functions. [Source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5998#issuecomment-311965292)

Comment: Cool this is what I was looking for. & Source is legit, from creator of Vue.js... so.

Answer (score 0):

You can call any mixin method with `Vue` instead `this`:

```js
// Mixins:
Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        parseDateTicks: str => str.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "")
    }
});


// Filters:
Vue.filter('dateTime', (date) => {
    if (date) {
        return new Date(+Vue.parseDateTicks(date)).toLocaleString();
    }
});
```